# Encontrar maior valor de soma e mostrar id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fala galera, tudo certo?

Tenho esta tabela

Tabela EMPREGADO_PROJETO

```
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| rg_empregado | num_projeto | horas |  
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| 20202020     | 5           | 10    |  
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| 20202020     | 10          | 25    |  
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| 30303030     | 5           | 35    | 
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| 40404040     | 20          | 50    | 
+--------------+-------------+-------+
| 50505050     | 20          | 35    | 
+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

Preciso mostrar qual é o projeto que tem mais horas. Pra isso precisarei juntar os projetos com mesmo numero, somar as horas deles e mostrar qual é a maior soma. A soma eu estou conseguindo mostrar, só falta identificar qual é o número do projeto que esta soma pertence.

Aqui o que consegui fazer até agora.

```
SELECT MAX(HORAS_TOTAIS) AS MAIOR_CARGA_HORARIA FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT NUM_PROJETO, SUM(HORAS) AS HORAS_TOTAIS FROM EMPREGADO_PROJETO
GROUP BY NUM_PROJETO) EMPREGADO_PROJETO
```

A resposta do Raphael deu certo, só precisei adicionar o top 1 no primeiro select e funcionou exatamente como eu queria.

Comment: thinker, não fique postando atualizações da pergunta aqui abaixo, como se fossem respostas. Clique em [edit] e adicione direto na pergunta, e apague os outros posts.

Comment: ok, está feito.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SELECT `num_projeto`, (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(HORAS)) AS HORAS_TOTAIS FROM EMPREGADO_PROJETO
GROUP BY num_projeto ORDER BY HORAS_TOTAIS DESC

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque a resposta completa, de preferência com resultado.

Comment: Ok, irei fazer aqui e mostra

Comment: Valeu pela resposta. Neste caso o rg_empregado não importa, somente o num_projeto e a carga horaria.

Comment: arrumado amigo @thinker

Comment: Opa, agora sim, deu certinho Raphael Caldas! Muito obrigado!

Comment: DownVoter por favor, diga-me oque errei.

Comment: Já votei velho, mas acho que sou usuário muito novo, ai ainda não ta contando.

Comment: não foi você, alguém deu downvote sem motivo aparente

Answer (score 0):

Acho que assim funciona, já que é para pegar o maior:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 total.horas_totais, total.rg, total.num_projeto
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT NUM_PROJETO as num_projeto,
           SUM(HORAS) AS horas_totais,
           RG_EMPREGADO as rg
           FROM EMPREGADO_PROJETO
           GROUP BY NUM_PROJETO
         ) total
    ORDER total.horas_totais DESC;
```

Ou

```
SELECT TOP 1 sum(horas) AS TOTAL_HORAS,
       NUM_PROJETO,
       RG_EMPREGADO
FROM  EMPREGADO_PROJETO
GROUP BY NUM_PROJETO ORDER BY TOTAL_HORAS desc;
```

Comment: Obrigado Ivan. As suas possíveis soluções não funcionaram.

Comment: As "minhas possíveis soluções" não foram testadas, eu costumo utilizar o MySQL, então você deve ter visto uma query "Frankenstein" é totalmente diferente o conceito. Mas eu tentei seguir a lógica do que você precisa, e do que você pediu na pergunta, deixarei mais claro na próxima. Obrigado você pela experiência.

Comment: Testei sim Ivan. Não quis desmerecer sua ajuda, longe disso. Talvez por meu conhecimento ainda ser baixo nesta área eu tenha testado de maneira errada. Desculpe se te ofendi, não era a intenção.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esta query resolva seu problema:

```
SELECT SUM(HORAS) AS HORAS, NUM_PROJETO FROM EMPREGADO_PROJETO
GROUP BY NUM_PROJETO
ORDER BY HORAS DESC
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, mas ainda não está como eu preciso.

Comment: O que você precisa a mais/menos?

Comment: Já foi resolvido. Da uma olhada no fim do primeiro post que eu expliquei.